# AWS SNS Push Notifications not sending

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

I have push notifications set up for sandbox iOS and they used to work but for some reason it's not working currently. This is the error AWS SNS from cloud watch logs:

```
{
"notification": {
    "messageMD5Sum": "39af77c36a92b71afb73212e74adf845",
    "messageId": "f8b4a21e-c3ba-52ed-8b17-ed36acf37e65",
    "timestamp": "2016-01-31 20:22:33.154"
},
"delivery": {
    "deliveryId": "a0941dde-8990-54ee-96e3-52f6e6d993d0",
    "destination": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:445291524102:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/BusyTime/a97020ec-4121-3995-a119-a7b6779ed602",
    "providerResponse": "NotificationErrorResponse(command=8, status=InvalidToken, id=1, cause=null)",
    "dwellTimeMs": 525,
    "attempts": 1,
    "token": "df6cb7064c391cc8ca1709c127b40f838768336c691512e00c73d01a18d6b0af",
    "statusCode": 8
},
"status": "FAILURE"
   }
```

This is my sending code (AWS Lambda invokes this code):

```
params = {"Attributes": { //update the endpoint
                    "Enabled": 'true',
                },
                "EndpointArn" : user.endpointARN.S
        }
        sns.setEndpointAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err){ 
                console.log(err, err.stack); 
            }
            else{     

                var paramsSNS = {
                    TargetArn:user.endpointARN.S,
                    Message:message
                };

                sns.publish(paramsSNS, function(err, data) {
                if (err){ 
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                }
                else{     
                    console.log(data);   
                    context.succeed(data);
                }
                });
            }       
        });
```

The return data from the Lambda method:

```
 {
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "61f9bc48-fd8b-5408-b7a9-f36093c023ad"
  },
  "MessageId": "657eaace-69aa-5f87-96dd-e5e607e1d822"
}
```

I have narrowed down the problem to not being associated with my lambda method since I've tried to publish to the endpoint that I've created directly from the SNS console. I'm also wondering why this old implementation had worked in the past, a month or two ago, and not anymore. I believe it might have to do with outdated certificates but I'm unsure how to check/I don't think I'd be receiving this kind of a provider response if my certificates were outdated.

Answer (score 0):

error states that the token is invalid. you might need to update the token as well aside from marking "Enabled = true". relevant blog post: http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx223MJB0XKV9RU/Mobile-token-management-with-Amazon-SNS

Comment: Token is updated every login. Also I've attempted to test it straight from the sns console  by manually inserting the token.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Are you passing the updated Device token to sns.createPlatformEndpoint() so SNS knows about it?